# Strategy for Caching Previous Searches (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, queue, fifo

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application (.NET 4, C#), **where user's can search for locations**.

The page is implemented with an auto-complete box, similar to many websites. (Google, YouTube, etc)

Now, the AJAX call to the server results in a Stored Procedure call to the database. (whilst efficient, could result in a lot of round-trips for slow typers).

I'm wondering how i can create a *strategy* to cache the result of say the last 100 searches?

I can't use OutputCache, as the call is made via AJAX on the client-side. I need to cache the output of the stored procedure (list of matched locations for a querytext).

In other words, a lot of people will search for "New York", or "San Francisco", and this data only changes via a manual admin change (where we could invalidate the cache manually, for example).

So, how could i cache the last 100 searches? I was hoping for a FIFO-like functionality, where if the cache already had 100 searches, the oldest one gets thrown away and everything get's moved down.

I want the code to be something like this:

```
public ICollection<MatchedLocation> FindLocations(string queryText)
{
    // Check last 100 searches.. How?
    string cacheKey = queryText;
    var matchedLocations = cachedPersistence.Get(cacheKey);

    if (matchedLocations == null)
    {
        // Call db
        matchedLocations = dbPersistence.GetLocations(queryText);

        // Add to cache
        cachedPersistence.Add(cacheKey, matchedLocations);
    }
    else
    {
        // Found in Cache! Awesome!
        return matchedLocations;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the obvious choice would be a .NET [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28VS.71%29.aspx)?

But i've never used that before, so any advice? How would i implement concurrency for the get/set, Would i need to use a fully-locked Singleton? Has anyone used a Queue for this purpose? What other options do we have? I would almost need a custom queue, to limit the number of items in the stack.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to cache a 100 you could use a Dictionary with a corresponding Dictionary with last used times. And you can use a reader writer lock instead of a full blown lock which allows multiple readers.

With the code below potentially two threads can enter `EnterWriteLock` for the same value. The penalty would be two db calls which might not be an issue. You can avoid this by doing another `TryGetValue` and locking (double locking) if necessary.

```
class Cache
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, ICollection<MatchedLocation>> _cache = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<MatchedLocation>>(100);
    static readonly Dictionary<string,DateTime> _cacheTimes = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>(100);
    static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public ICollection<MatchedLocation> FindLocations(string queryText)
    {
        _lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            ICollection<MatchedLocation> result;
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(queryText, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                _lock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    // expire cache items
                    if( _cache.Count > 100)
                    {
                        // could be more efficient http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ - MinBy
                        string key = _cacheTimes.OrderBy(item => item.Value).First().Key;
                        _cacheTimes.Remove(key);
                        _cache.Remove(key);
                    }
                    // add new item
                    result = dbPersistence.GetLocations(queryText);
                    _cache[queryText] = result;
                    _cacheTimes[queryText] = DateTime.UtcNow;                        
                }
                finally
                {
                    _lock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll try this out, run some tests and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: You might want to add a time expiration job in order to get updated DB data once in a while. Another approach is to use the Cache object in ASP.Net, and keep a counter and use expire triggers. I think it all depends on how much control you want over the cache, and how much data you need to cache to make the solution fly. Interesting read at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/2ea7a5bc-987b-4395-ab4f-f03890a3c0a0 which also talks about Velocity.

Comment: Also check out this small project - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=SimpleCache&ReleaseId=1171